# C# XML child node of similar sibling

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to modify an XML document that we didn't create initially. Snippit from XML is below:

```
<DEALS>
  <DEAL>
    <LOANS>
      <LOAN LoanRoleType="SubjectLoan">
        <BUYDOWN>
          <BUYDOWN_RULE>
            <BuydownInformation>0</BuydownInformation>
          </BUYDOWN_RULE>
        </BUYDOWN>
      </LOAN>
      <LOAN LoanRoleType="SubjectLoan">
        <LOAN_IDENTIFIERS>
          <LOAN_IDENTIFIER>
          ...
          </LOAN_IDENTIFIER>
          <LOAN_IDENTIFIER>
            <SellerLoanIdentifier>1234567890</SellerLoanIdentifier>
          </LOAN_IDENTIFIER>
        </LOAN_IDENTIFIERS>
      </LOAN>
    </LOANS>
  </DEAL>
  <DEAL>
    ...Same format as above...
  </DEAL>
</DEALS>
```

The first `LOAN` element of each `DEAL` will never contain `LOAN_IDENTIFIERS`. I need to get the `SellerLoanIdentifier`'s InnerText, and then put it into `<BuydownInformation>` of the first `LOAN` element. I've tried nested loops and can't seem to get it to differentiate between the two `LOAN` elements (the second loop isn't even seeing the `LOAN` elements). I'm thinking it also might have to do with the fact that they both carry the exact same attribute but can't find anything online up to this point to help.

```
XmlDocument xmlExport = new XmlDocument();
xmlExport.Load(fileDestination);

string loanNumber = "";

XmlNodeList loan_XMLDeals = xmlExport.GetElementsByTagName("DEAL");
Logger.WriteDebug("Found " + loan_XMLDeals.Count + " Deals");
foreach (XmlNode loan_XMLDeal in loan_XMLDeals)
{
    XmlNodeList loan_XMLLoans = loan_XMLDeal.SelectNodes("LOAN");
    Logger.WriteDebug("Found " + loan_XMLLoans.Count + " Loan categories");
    foreach (XmlNode loan_XMLCategory in loan_XMLLoans)
    {
        if(loan_XMLCategory.SelectSingleNode("SellerLoanIdentifier") != null)
        {
            loanNumber = loan_XMLCategory.SelectSingleNode("SellerLoanIdentifier").ToString();
            Logger.WriteDebug("Got loan number " + loanNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't put your Google Search in the title of your question, unless that's what you're actually asking.  If it is, you need to clarify a bit more in your post.

Comment: So, exactly 2 `LOAN` elements per `DEAL`, copy (nested) value of `SellerLoanIdentifier` of 2nd `LOAN` element into (nested) `BuydownInformation` of first `LOAN` element? Correct?

Comment: Yes @spender that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

This becomes a lot easier with linq to xml. This means ditching the (old) `XmlDocument` and replacing it with the friendlier `XDocument`.

Instead of searching the whole document for the target, you need to start from the context of where you found the `SellerLoanIdentifier`. You can walk back up to the `LOAN` element, find its previous sibling, then search that for the `BuydownInformation`. Because this was all scoped within a single `LOANS` entry, you can be sure you're targeting the right element.

So...

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(fileDestination);
//we're going to select a sequence of items that contain 2 values...
//the element we want to change and the value we want to store in it
var changes= doc.Root
                .Elements("DEAL")
                .Descendants("SellerLoanIdentifier")
                //from each SellerLoanIdentifier in DEAL elements
                .Select(e => new{
                    //the node we want to change
                    //in this case we get the parent LOAN
                    //element, take the last of the elements
                    //that precede it in the document
                    //(e.g. the previous sibling which
                    //contains the target node)
                    //and find in it a descendant of type
                    //BuydownInformation
                    nodeToChange = e.Ancestors("LOAN")
                                    .Single()
                                    .ElementsBeforeSelf()
                                    .Last()
                                    .Descendants("BuydownInformation")
                                    .Single(),
                    //the string value of the current element
                    val = (string)e
                });
//then apply the changes back to the document
foreach(var change in changes)
{
    change.nodeToChange.Value = change.val;
}
var newXmlString = doc.ToString();
```

There are assumptions here about the shape of your data that may not hold true, but it should be relatively easy to modify.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple XML Linq code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            List<XElement> loans = doc.Descendants("LOANS").ToList();
            foreach (XElement loan in loans)
            {
                string sellerLoanIdentifier = (string)loan.Descendants("SellerLoanIdentifier").FirstOrDefault();
                XElement buydownInformation = loan.Descendants("BuydownInformation").FirstOrDefault();
                buydownInformation.Value = sellerLoanIdentifier;
            }
        }
    }
}
```